# Can I change Solr data-config.xml file using code?

Tags: solr

I am indexing my database table rows in chunks and my query looks like this:

`SELECT S.test_file_result_id,S.syndrome, TDR.start_date AS start_date, TL.job_id AS job_id FROM Syndrome S STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_File_Result TF ON TF.id = S.test_file_result_id STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_Directory_Result TDR ON TDR.id=TF.test_directory_result_id STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_Run TR ON TR.id = TDR.test_run_id STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_Log TL ON TL.id = TR.test_log_id WHERE S.test_file_result_id between ? AND ?`

I need to provide different values for both the ? and then index the result of the query.

Is there any way to change the query or pass values as parameter at run-time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the data import handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [data import handler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler), then you can pass parameter (say called `param`) when invoking the import URL and access it like `${dataimporter.request.param}` inside your data-config.xml.

You can specify your query like:

`SELECT S.test_file_result_id,S.syndrome, TDR.start_date AS start_date, TL.job_id AS job_id FROM Syndrome S STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_File_Result TF ON TF.id = S.test_file_result_id STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_Directory_Result TDR ON TDR.id=TF.test_directory_result_id STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_Run TR ON TR.id = TDR.test_run_id STRAIGHT_JOIN Test_Log TL ON TL.id = TR.test_log_id WHERE S.test_file_result_id between ${dataimporter.request.min_id} AND ${dataimporter.request.max_id}`

and invoke the import like:

`/dataimport?command=full-import&min_id=1&max_id=1000`